# RxJS scan to accumulate database results using filter and offset as url parameters

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have two behaviorSubjects

`offset = new behaviorSubject<sring>(null)`
`filter = new behaviorSubject<string>(null)`

I do the following..

```
combineLatest(
    this.offset, // last item in the list, ID for example
    this.filter //  can be any string
).pipe(
    mergeMap(([offset, filter]) => this.getChunkOfTen(offset, filter)),
    scan((acc, chunkOfTen) => {
        return { ...acc, ...chunkOfTen }
    }, {}),
    map(results => Object.values(results)) // to be able to loop on the frontend
)
```

When the page loads I get 10 records from DB, onScroll I get 10 more and 10 more.. that's what **mergeMap** and **scan** are in charge of (as expected).

onFilter all the existing records are gone (as expected) and I get NEW 10 filtered records from DB, NOW when I scroll I DO NOT get more records and I have them in DB.

as far as I know the problem lays.. in **scan** operator

is there an if else operator? or some other operators I can use before **scan**?

Comment: It feels like you're having 2 distinct problems here, please specify EXACTLY what piece of code would you like us to review.

Comment: Thank you Sereja, question was updated

Answer (score 0):

Nothing stops you from climbing one-abstraction-level-up and deal with so called "higher order observables" - those, which are of the type... `Observable<Observable<T>>`. Also documentation states:

> Be aware that combineLatest will not emit an initial value until each
>   observable emits at least one value. This is the same behavior as
>   withLatestFrom and can be a gotcha as there will be no output and no
>   error but one (or more) of your inner observables is likely not
>   functioning as intended, or a subscription is late.

If you feel like my answer has nothing to do with you problem, than please provide more details and I'll update myself.

---

Nope, `scan` most probably isn't a cause here. `combineLatest` is. First of all, it can't be seen when both filtering and scrolling call `next`; one of them might even `complete` and if that is the case, here you go. Secondly, `scan` is `reduce` with extra feature: it `next`s not only the final result of reduction, but intermediate results as well, that's it, nothing else. Last, but not the least, you might decide to plug `tap(console.log)` (or rely on the `debugger`) all over your pipes to quickly inspect what's going on.

Comment: @Sereje, I had this issue when using `filter` and `offset` just as normal variables of type `string`. I manged to solve this issue with a simple `if else` inside `scan` so I know for sure that the problem lays in `scan`, all I'm looking for is a way to solve this reactively.

Comment: @Sereje, I'm not `filtering` and `scrolling` on the same time. first I `filter` to get the records then I `scroll`.

Comment: @user12163165, just append all the code, including scrolling/filtering handling.

Answer (score 0):

found where the problem was..
it is not in `combineLatest` nor `scan`
after `filtering` all I needed to do is to reset `offset` observable back to `null` so it can get a new `offset` from the filtered items in the list.